# Recognized and enabled Elantech touchpad not working

Tags: xorg, touchpad, synaptics, elantech

Recognized and enabled touchpad not working at all on a Toshiba L55D-C5269 Laptop.
A search yields many different solutions to Elan touchpads but none of them seem to be working.

Some of the things I tried:

-Tweaked xorg conf files in various ways

-Installed Libinput and uninstalled Synaptics

-Resetted BIOS

Some other people solved their issue by updating their kernel but mine was up-to-date anyway...

I am quite new to Linux so I'm hoping that I just missed a simple, small detail and that there is an easy fix.

Here is some info that you may need:

cat /proc/bus/input/devices

```
I: Bus=0011 Vendor=0002 Product=000e Version=0000
N: Name="ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"
P: Phys=isa0060/serio1/input0
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/i8042/serio1/input/input6
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event5 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e420 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=661800011000003
```

xinput --list

```
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Optical Mouse                id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ TOSHIBA Web Camera - HD                   id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Toshiba input device                      id=13   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

xinput list 12

```
ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                    id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 10 classes:
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 12
        Button labels: "Button Left" "Button Middle" "Button Right" "Button Wheel Up" "Button Wheel Down" "Button Horiz Wheel Left" "Button Horiz Wheel Right" None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Rel X
          Range: 0.000000 - 3260.000000
          Resolution: 33000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Rel Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 1956.000000
          Resolution: 33000 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: Rel Horiz Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: Rel Vert Scroll
          Range: 0.000000 - -1.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: relative
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 4:
          Label: Abs MT Touch Major
          Range: 0.000000 - 2445.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 5:
          Label: Abs MT Pressure
          Range: 0.000000 - 255.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 2
          type: 2 (horizontal)
          increment: 76.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XIScrollClass
        Scroll info for Valuator 3
          type: 1 (vertical)
          increment: 76.000000
          flags: 0x0
        Class originated from: 12. Type: XITouchClass
        Touch mode: dependent
        Max number of touches: 5
```

xinput list-props "ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad"

```
  Device 'ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad':
        Device Enabled (137):      1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (139):      1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (262):      1
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (263):      2.500000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (264):      1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (265):      12.500000
        Synaptics Edges (266):      1744, 5200, 2000, 4256
        Synaptics Finger (267):      1, 1, 0
        Synaptics Tap Time (268):      180
        Synaptics Tap Move (269):      167
        Synaptics Tap Durations (270):      180, 100, 100
        Synaptics ClickPad (271):      1
        Synaptics Middle Button Timeout (272):      0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Pressure (273):      282
        Synaptics Two-Finger Width (274):      7
        Synaptics Scrolling Distance (275):      76, 76
        Synaptics Edge Scrolling (276):      0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Two-Finger Scrolling (277):      1, 1
        Synaptics Move Speed (278):      1.000000, 1.750000, 0.052618, 0.000000
        Synaptics Off (279):      2
        Synaptics Locked Drags (280):      0
        Synaptics Locked Drags Timeout (281):      5000
        Synaptics Tap Action (282):      2, 3, 0, 0, 1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Click Action (283):      1, 3, 0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling (284):      0
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Distance (285):      0.100000
        Synaptics Circular Scrolling Trigger (286):      0
        Synaptics Circular Pad (287):      0
        Synaptics Palm Detection (288):      0
        Synaptics Palm Dimensions (289):      10, 200
        Synaptics Coasting Speed (290):      20.000000, 50.000000
        Synaptics Pressure Motion (291):      30, 160
        Synaptics Pressure Motion Factor (292):      1.000000, 1.000000
        Synaptics Resolution Detect (293):      1
        Synaptics Grab Event Device (294):      0
        Synaptics Gestures (295):      1
        Synaptics Capabilities (296):      1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1
        Synaptics Pad Resolution (297):      33, 33
        Synaptics Area (298):      0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Soft Button Areas (299):      1630, 0, 1603, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        Synaptics Noise Cancellation (300):      19, 19
        Device Product ID (255):      2, 14
        Device Node (256):      "/dev/input/event5"
```

uname -a

```
Linux UB 4.4.0-59-generic #80-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 6 17:47:47 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

synclient -l

```
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 130
    RightEdge               = 3130
    TopEdge                 = 105
    BottomEdge              = 1851
    FingerLow               = 1
    FingerHigh              = 1
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 167
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 100
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 76
    HorizScrollDelta        = 76
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 1
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0526177
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 2
    RBCornerButton          = 3
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 3
    TapButton3              = 0
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 0
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    CircularPad             = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    ResolutionDetect        = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 0
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 19
    VertHysteresis          = 19
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 1630
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 1603
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Comment: NOTE - As of this date (06DEC2018), Windows 10 is having major problems with I2C touchpads not even enumerating. Therefore, do not use Windows 10 as a sanity check for touchpad hardware at the moment!

Answer (score 3):

Some Acer laptops, such as the Spin 5, have a touchpad lockout that is accessed by pressing FN+F7 (or just F7, depending on BIOS configuration).

Both the ELAN touchpad, and the touchscreen, on an Acer Spin 5 will work under Xorg for Fedora 28 with NO xorg.conf file, provided the lockout is DISABLED.  The touchscreen will work even if the lockout is disabled.

Comment: OMG! I can't believe it was this simple. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! I'd never understood what the symbol meant on F7, and it fixed my problem immediately: I'd pressed it by mistake.  Note: it *stays disabled through reboot*, and there is no user interface feedback that I've found to show the state (ie, in control panel). Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

this is not a ubuntu problem.

I solved it this way:

- reboot laptop, (F2) to enter the BIOS.
- Pressed FN+F5. Touchpad start to work (you press again FN+F5 it is disabled again).
- Booting Ubuntu and it just works as it was before.

Comment: I didn't even need to enter bios. Did it on arch itself.